# How to launch a test on every lines of a file in bash?

Tags: bash, parsing, grep, xargs

I have a file that contains lines of the form:

```
(  1) 0 sec 730 usec
(  2) 0 sec 1 usec
(  3) 0 sec 1 usec
.
.
.
(998) 0 sec 1 usec
(999) 0 sec 0 usec
```

I would like to only display lines which contains more than 100 usec

I tried to use xargs but my attempts failed.
I also tried to write a bash script with a while loop, storing my file inside an ARG variable. But I don't know how to make my while loop parse through every single lines of ARG...

How to do that in both ways please ? Thanks

Comment: Edit your question and include the code you tried in code blocks.

Comment: Is there some reason not to use `awk`?

Comment: No, I just dont know how to use awk very well and wanted a fast way of achieving this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `awk`

Match lines with 5 fields if the 4th field is greater than or equal to 100 or match lines with 6 fields if the 5th field is greater than or equal to 100.

```
awk '(NF==5 && $4>=100) || (NF==6 && $5>=100) {print $0}' src.dat 
(  1) 0 sec 730 usec
```

src.dat contents:

```
(  1) 0 sec 730 usec
(  2) 0 sec 1 usec
(  3) 0 sec 1 usec
.
.
.
(998) 0 sec 1 usec
(999) 0 sec 0 usec
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `awk`

```
awk '$(NF-1) > 100' file.txt
```

and counting backward to avoid dealing with the extra spaces in the first field.

Comment: This assumes that `usec` won't roll over into the `sec` field.  Something like `$(NF-3) > 0 || $(NF-1) > 100` might work better.